# OpenLayers - markers not displayed

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript

I just started worrking with OpenLayers and hava a problem with markers that don´t appear.
I have no idea where is the problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function init() {
    var center = new OpenLayers.LonLat(17.55, 53.7).transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:900913');
    var map = new OpenLayers.Map("map");
    var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
    map.addLayer(osm);
    map.setCenter(center, 12);


    var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers("Markers");
    map.addLayer(markers);
    var size = new OpenLayers.Size(21, 25);
    var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w / 2), -size.h);
    var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon('http://www.openlayers.org/dev/img/marker.png', size, offset);
    var table;

    console.log(map);


$.getJSON('url',

function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    $.each(data.response.venues, function (i, venues) {

        markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(new OpenLayers.LonLat(venues.location.lng, venues.location.lat).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913")), icon));
        markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(new OpenLayers.LonLat(venues.location.lng, venues.location.lat).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913")), icon.clone()));
    });
});
}
```

**1 UPDATE**: `map.addLayers(markers)` changed to `map.addLayer(markers)`
**2 UPDATE**: put the getJSON call in the init() function

Comment: Should you have left your client_id and client_secret in the URL like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things. First, all your variables defined in `init()` are out of scope when the JSON function runs. Fix that by putting the `getJSON` call in the `init()` function too, or defining the map and other variables in the global scope (especially if you want to do anything else with them).

Secondly, `map.addLayer(markers)` instead of `map.addLayers(markers)`. There's only one marker layer, so use the singular.

Comment: i corrected the second suggestion but as i´m new to web programming i don´t really know how to put the `getJSON call` in the `init()` function. Any suggestion where i can find some information about it, as so far i haven't found anything.

Comment: Just put the curly bracket that closes the init function just before the closing </script> tag. Then all the JS in the script tags is one big init file which gets run "onLoad" as specified in your HTML.

Comment: That works!!! thanx